# Pattern Recognition OR Named Entity Recognition for Information Extraction in NLP

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction, opennlp, pattern-recognition, information-extraction

There are some event description texts.
I want to extract the entrance fee of the events.
Sometimes the entrance fee is conditional.

What I want to achieve is to extract the entrance fee and it's conditions(if available). It's fine to retrieve the whole phrase or sentence which tells the entrance fee + it's conditions.

Note I: The texts are in German language.
Note II: Often the sentences are not complete, as they are mainly event flyers or advertisements.

What would be the category of this problem in NLP? Is it Named Entity Recognition and could be solved by training an own model with Apache openNLP?
Or I thought maybe easier would be to detect the pattern via the usual keywords in the use-case(entrance, $, but, only till, [number]am/pm, ...).

Please shed some light on me.

Input Examples: 
- "If you enter the club before 10pm, the entrance is for free. Afterwards it is 6$."
- "Join our party tonight at 11pm till 5am. The entrance fee is 8$. But for girls and students it's half price."

Answer (score 1):

This is broadly a structure learning problem. You might have to combine Named-Entity-Recognition/Tagging with Coreference Resolution. Read some papers on these as well as related github code and take it from there. Here is good discussion of state of the art tools for these at the moment https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3dz3fl/dl_architectures_for_entity_recognition_and_other/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

You might try Stanford's CoreNLP for the named entity extraction part. It should be able to help you pick out the money values, and there is also a link to models trained for German language as well (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).

Given that it's fine to extract the entire sentence that contains the information, I'd suggest taking a binary sentence classification approach. You could probably get quite far just by using ngrams and some named entity information as features. That would mean that you'd need you'd want to build a pipeline that would automatically segment your documents into sentence-like chunks. You could try a sentence segmentation tool (also provided by Stanford CoreNLP) as a first go https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/. Since this would form the basis for all further work, you'd want to ensure that the results are at least decent. Perhaps the structure of the document itself gives you enough information to segment it without even using a sentence segmentation tool.

After you have this pipeline in place, you'd want to annotate the sentences extracted from a large set of documents as relevant or non-relevant to make it a binary classification task. Then train a model based on that dataset. Finally, when you apply it to unseen data, first use the sentence segmentation approach, and then classify each sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain a bit more detailed how I can find the related sentences to the "entrance"? Or I should train the model?